# How to set a specific webform in page object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The following line gives me the current page in c# web application asp.net using c#. However I want to set a specific page from my web application like Webform2.aspx every time I use function.

```
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
```

I haven't found anything related to this on the internet. Is it even possible?

EDIT: FOR EXPLANATION

See the above line code gives me the current webform in the page object. Right?
There is another webform let us say WEBFORM2 in my application. I want to get that Webform2 in this page object. How can I get that ?

Comment: What do you mean "set a page"? Like, you want to redirect the user to a page?

Comment: Please explain your problem correctly

Comment: I just want to get a webform in this page object.

Comment: But.. why ? What are you trying to do ?